# how do I check if a domain name is available (in bulk)?

Tags: perl, dns

I am looking to do a bulk domain name lookup to see if some domain names are available for purchase. I couldn't find a perl module, but it seems like there should be a way to do this in perl. I am looking for something free. thx!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463336/recommended-apis-for-checking-domain-availability or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523260/recommendations-for-domain-name-registrar-with-api-support

Comment: actually, this is not a duplicate. I am looking for something free....those people are asking for paid versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=625723

Here’s a quick perl script that requires Net :: DNS (fairly common module).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Domains Available
# Josh Skidmore <josh@vorcado.com>
# 05 August 2007 | 11:40p EST

# Requirements
    use Net::DNS;

# Variables
    %VAR    =   (
                    db => './domains.txt',
                );

# Open file
    open (DB,$VAR{'db'});
    my (@domains) = <DB>;
    close (DB);

# Test domains
    foreach my $domain (@domains)
        {
            chomp($domain);

            my ($available) = &check_domain(domain => $domain);

            if ($available)
                {
                    print "$domain is available.<br />\n";
                }
            else
                {
                    print "$domain is NOT available<br />\n";
                }
        }

sub check_domain {

    # Test domain for existance
    # Josh Skidmore <josh@vorcado.com>
    # 05 August 2007 | 11:42p EST

    # Variables
        my (%DATA) = @_ ;
        my ($available) = 0;

    # Start Net::DNS
        my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;
        $res->udp_timeout(2);
        $res->tcp_timeout(2);

        my ($domain) = $res->search($DATA{'domain'});

        if ($domain)
            {
                ($available) = 1;
            }

    # Output
        return ($available);
}
```

Comment: I saw that one but as is pointed out in the next answer on that board, the fact that a domain doesn't resolve doesn't mean it's available

Comment: And its expensive to create the Net::DNS::Resolver object for each request.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of [whois-like modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=whois&mode=all). `Net::Whois::Parser` looks promising, for one.

Barring that, the `whois` command is available in Linux and other Unix-y systems (including Cygwin for windows). There's also a [`whois` script in Perl on CPAN](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CWEST/ppt-0.14/html/commands/whois/whois.tweton). Running those programs is the easy part. The tricky part, which Perl can definitely help with, is parsing the output from those programs.